# ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

Tags: python, python-3.x, connection, hdfs

I'm trying to connecting to HDFS in python code that I write in Jupyternotebook:

```
    from hdfs import InsecureClient

    client_hdfs = InsecureClient('host/:port', user='marina.i')
    with client_hdfs.read('/user-data/.csv', encoding = 'utf-8') as reader:
        df = pd.read_csv(reader,index_col=0)
```

I'm getting an error:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: did you got an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify real `HDFS_URL` as the first parameter of `InsecureClient`.

Comment: Yes I gave a real URL, just here in the example I've deleted it

Comment: Try to use telnet to connect to real URL and to check that URL is correct and you have access to remote host.